# Change mouse cursor in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-cursor

How can I change the mouse cursor in Javascript or in jQuery ? I know it's a very classic question, but very strangely this JSFiddle doesn't work : http://jsfiddle.net/2Qffw/.

Here is the code :

```
$('body').css('cursor','pointer');

document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

Comment: Try locally without jsFiddle, and it should work, or try an element in jsFiddle and it works as well -> http://jsfiddle.net/2Qffw/1/

Comment: The nicest way of doing this is with a CSS rule using :hover. Can you model your app that way instead?

Comment: @adeneo : locally, it works without <!DOCTYPE html>, but not with.

Comment: @cirrus : it's not really my problem. In fact, I've largely reduced my problem to that I presented in my question.

Comment: This doesn't seem like something you should be doing with jQuery instead of plain old CSS.

Comment: @Corion, not true.  CSS only restricts the change to only the item over which you are pointing.  That's capricious unless it's the body or HTML, then it's permanent.  I'm here to find a way to change the cursor while a file is uploading, and then change it back when the upload is complete.  That's not a CSS problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Do it in both `html` and `body`:

```
$('html,body').css('cursor','crosshair');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Qffw/3/

Answer (score 12):

It does work, but you had an empty body.

http://jsfiddle.net/z6mhH/

HTML

```
<body>
    asdasdasdasdads
</body>
```

JS

```
document.body.style.cursor = "crosshair";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.cursor="move";
```

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript, you can do it, you just have to use `void 0;` at the end of `document.body.style.cursor = "crosshair";`, so at the end, it should look like this: `document.body.style.cursor = "crosshair"; void 0;`.