# How to change the mouse cursor with javascript without hovering an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, mouse

I know we can use HTMLElement.style.cursor to change a cursor when hovering an element. But can we change the cursor using javascript without the need of mouse hovering anything? Thanks.

This is for a game app on the web/web view

*I need a solution that does not depend on the dom*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414034/change-mouse-cursor-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @KimGysen Obviously its a different question

Comment: @KimGysen the cursor would be dependent on the dom. for example, if you change the cursor on the current element you are hovering over, you move your mouse and your cursor changes

Comment: Yes, but your scripts interact with the browser through the browser's DOM api... I don't think that there is another way to do it afaik, and I don't really think that there is a need to. The proposed solutions should work?

Comment: hence the question... If there is any api/library to interact with the mouse directly it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

change the cursor for all elements: http://jsfiddle.net/m2rLy13L/1/

```
$('*').css('cursor','help');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a div that will wrap the entire document: http://jsfiddle.net/ymzrocks/un8b6rbc/

html:

```
<div class="frame" style="background:#ababab"></div>
<div class="frame">
content here
</div>
```

css:

```
.frame
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    ;
}
```

js:

```
$('div.frame').css('cursor', 'help');
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer not to use a div wrapper as I need to click on the html. I would like to use something like `mouse.cursor('crosshair')` so its easier and cleaner.

Comment: try fiddle - the wrapper is at the background not at the front.

Comment: Thanks, but it breaks when there is something in front... http://jsfiddle.net/m2rLy13L/

Comment: i just watch you fiddle and it works. **console.log** prints to the developer console not to the screen. it is just fine if you don't like my solution, but when you say that it breaks it may confuse other users

Comment: Sorry, I meant the mouse cursor changes in front of the button. the button itself works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems https://www.npmjs.org/package/pointer-cursor might be a good package to use.